# Why can I mark methods as implicit but not the constructor?

Tags: class, scala, constructor, implicit, enrich-my-library

The common Enrich-My-Library pattern seems to be something like

```
class Foo(value: Int)

implicit def int2Foo(i: Int) = new Foo(i)
```

Why isn't it possible to just add the `implicit` to the constructor itself like this

```
class Foo implicit (value: Int)
```

considering that the constructor isn't much more than a method with some additional restriction?

Surprisingly, the following does work:

```
class Foo(value: Int) {
  implicit def this(a: String) = this(a.toInt)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) you mean ? If so, there's a [tag for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pimp-my-library).

Comment: FYI: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4882

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (see my comment above) what you are thinking of amounts to this:

```
implicit class Foo(val i : Int) {
 ...
}
```

Would amount to:

```
implicit def int2Foo(x : Int) = new Foo(x)
class Foo(val i : Int) {
 ...
}
```

If it's more than desugaring you have in mind, [there probably is some more thought to be given to the problem](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/20187/focus=20204) to avoid over-complexifying the semantics of the constructor declaration.

But as far as the small-scale syntax addition goes, this has been [suggested](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/3455), and has [received nuanced but relatively positive comments](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/3459) from Martin Odersky, but I have no news on implementation yet.

Comment: No, not really ... why would we need desugaring here? My ideas was simply allowing to add `implicit` to the constructor. Adding `implicit` to a class? No idea what the semantics should be ...

Comment: In that case, what would  "allowing to add implicit to the constructor" mean, else than the desugaring I suggest above ?

Comment: I just don't see the point of your desugaring suggestion. It doesn't work like that currently, why should it be added for some "special case"?

Comment: Just for reference, this syntax change has been accepted: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html